# Aggregate values from customMeasurements column

Tags: azure-data-explorer

For my company I need to extract data from Azure Application Insights. 
All the relevant data is stored in the customMeasurements. Currently, the table looks something like this:

```
name       | itemType        | customMeasurements
-----------------------------------------------------------
AppName    | customEvent     | {
                                Feature1:1,
                                Feature2:0,
                                Feature3:0
                               }
-----------------------------------------------------------
AppName    | customEvent     | {
                                Feature1:0,
                                Feature2:1,
                                Feature3:0
                               }
```

I'm trying to find a Kusto query which will aggregate all enabled features (which would have a value of '1'), but I'm unable to do so.

I tried several things to get this resolved like the following:

```
customEvents
| extend test = tostring(customMeasurements.["Feature2"])
| summarize count() by test
```

This actually showed me the number rows that have Feature2 set to '1' but I want to be able to extract all features that have been enabled without specifying them in the query (as they can have custom names).

Could somebody point me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, something like the following could give you a direction:

```
datatable(name:string, itemType:string, customMeasurements:dynamic)
[
    'AppName', 'customEvent', dynamic({"Feature1":1,"Feature2":0,"Feature3":0}),
    'AppName', 'customEvent', dynamic({"Feature1":0,"Feature2":1,"Feature3":0}),
]
| mv-apply customMeasurements on
(
    extend feature = tostring(bag_keys(customMeasurements)[0])
    | where customMeasurements[feature] == 1
)
| summarize enabled_features = make_set(feature) by name
```

Comment: Through the example Yoni L provided I was able to get it working. Thanks a lot!